# Javascript, I'm not being able to set focus to html form element

Tags: javascript

I know that I had to search on google, youtube and stackoverflow before I ask my question on stackoverflow.

But I swear I watched many videos on youtube, And I searched for many ways on google and stackoverflow! to solve my problem.
,

And now i'm stuck with this

```
<input id="input-sign-in-id" class="uqid-id-input touch-feedback textfield-validate theme-textfield hokkai-text-input insert-dir three-point-leader" dir="auto" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="64" type="email">
```

I can set any value via this code, And it works.

```
var t2 = document.getElementById("input-sign-in-id");
t2.value = "LuxuryUAE2@hotmail.com";
```

But the problem is I can't set focus to the input, I tried this code, And it doesn't work.

```
var t2 = document.getElementById("input-sign-in-id");
t2.focus();
t2.click();
t2.select();
```

Comment: That looks perfectly fine, probably something else is causing a problem. For the beginning, you could try replacing `var` with `let`, maybe `t2` variable is getting overwritten by hoisting.

Comment: Did you ensure that the Dom is rendered before calling `focus() `?

Comment: @Deda *variable is getting overwritten by hoisting* What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: @connexo I'm saying, that there is a chance that he defined a `t2` variable on some other place and since `var` defined variables are hoisted, lastly defined value is assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JavaScript looks correct. You should be able to focus on the input element with the following code:

`document.getElementById("input-sign-in-id").focus()`

There are a lot of CSS classes on that input element that may be affecting the focus styles of that element. Also, there may be ID-specific CSS affecting too.

Try removing all of the classes and if see if it works. Then slowly add them back one by one, until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following and see if it works :

```
window.setTimeout(function () { 
    document.getElementById('input-sign-in-id').focus(); 
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function setFocus(){
    document.getElementById("input-sign-in-id").focus();
}
```

```html
<input id="input-sign-in-id">
```

You can use javascript for focusing:

```
<input id="input-sign-in-id">
```

Your script for focus would be

```
<script>
function setFocus(){
    document.getElementById("input-sign-in-id").focus();
}
</script>
```